# How to limit the clickable area of this menu to its text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why is the whole width clickable and how can I change that?

Obviously the only clickable area should be the text when visible, nothing else.

I've tried display: inline-block but it messed up the menu.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/180xhfwk/1/)

Thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
    <li class="menu-level-1"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="menu-level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1-2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-level-1"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="menu-level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Item 2-1</a>
            <ul class="menu-level-3">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2-1-1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-level-1"><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="menu-level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-level-1"><a href="#">Item 4</a>
        <ul class="menu-level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Item 4-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4-2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
}

li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.menu-level-1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu-level-2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle it seems to work exactly as you want it? You can use display:inline-block, but you then must add float:left; clear:both; if you want the list items to be vertical rather than horizontal!

Comment: Your on click isn't targeting the text, it's targeting the class .menu-level-1 and the width of that class is more than the width of the text. Hover your mouse of the menu, Red background is the text width and green is the class width http://jsfiddle.net/180xhfwk/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it now. What would you suggest to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your CSS and use display: table.

```
ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Yet another solution... wow so many! I think I actually prefer this one as it does not alter my original script. May I ask why you added margin-bottom? It's not necessary, is it?

Comment: It was for testing in your fiddle, I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

The whole width is clickable because li elements have the list-item display, whose behavior specifies that their width is 100%.  This is misleading because only the anchor tags have the pointer cursor.

I updated your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/180xhfwk/2/) with the following:

```
$('.menu-level-1 a').on('click', function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    ...
});
```

It now binds the click listener to the the anchor tags themselves, rather than the .menu-level-1 things and functions as I think you expect it to.

Comment: That way, clicking the 2nd column closes it. It shouldn't. :(

Comment: I updated it!

http://jsfiddle.net/180xhfwk/5/

I changed the selector from .menu-level-1 a to .menu-level-1 > a.  I think it works as you want now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using click event for **li**, use click event for **anchor** 
and in traversing use **parent()**

Jquery:

```
$('.menu-level-2').hide();
$('.menu-level-1 > a').on('click', function(){      
  if(!($(this).parent().children('.menu-level-2').is(':visible'))){
      $('.menu-level-2').slideUp();
      $(this).parent().children('.menu-level-2').slideDown();
    } else {
    $('.menu-level-2').slideUp();
  }
});
$('.menu-level-2').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

here is the JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/180xhfwk/4/